# What is the difference between Dell Bios and Dell firmware?

Tags: dell-poweredge

On the Dell Support site, looking on the available downloads for my old server, I see both

- Dell Bios Update - Optional 5/23/2008 A07

and

- Dell-Firmware - Recommended 9/4/2007 A.04, A04

What is the difference between?

Do I need to do both?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by reading http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdup/dup62/en/ug/linux/html/3onliner.htm it seems that Dell servers have a traditional BIOS -- effectively they are "souped-up" PCs -- but also have firmware for various other controllers in the machine.

So, yes, it seems you need both.